# How to do basic authentication using Selenium Webdriver and PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm having trouble authenticating using Selenium Server 2.33.0, Selenium Webdriver JS binding 2.34.0 (npm package "selenium-webdriver") and PhantomJS 1.9.1 on Mac 10.6.8.  I've also tried the other JS bindings "webdriverjs" and "wd" with the similar results so I don't think it's a problem with this binding.

I setup the Webdriver using this:

```
return new Webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities({
        "browserName": "phantomjs",
        "phantomjs.page.settings.userName":user,
        "phantomjs.page.settings.password":password
    }).build();
```

I then see in the Selenium Server log this output:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2013-08-13T21:52:40.240Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 28904
[INFO  - 2013-08-13T21:52:40.394Z] Session [acd0ad70-0462-11e3-95df-4b230b17334d] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired Capabilities:{"phantomjs.page.settings.password":"xxx","browserName":"phantomjs","phantomjs.page.settings.userName":"xxx"}
[INFO  - 2013-08-13T21:52:40.394Z] Session [acd0ad70-0462-11e3-95df-4b230b17334d] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.3","platform":"mac-10.6 (Snow Leopard)-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"},"phantomjs.page.settings.password":"xxx","phantomjs.page.settings.userName":"xxx"}
```

I can see that the negotiated capabilities contain the user and password I specified.  But the authentication fails when I try to open a page in a website that uses http basic authentication:

```
14:43:25.504 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: auth-username-field-inputEl] at URL: /session/04627dc2-a16c-42b3-b3dc-48e502f7cfec/element)
14:43:29.410 WARN - Exception thrown org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with id 'auth-username-field-inputEl''
```

If I run my script against the localhost website that doesn't have authentication, it works fine. If I view the remote website using Firefox (not via Selenium), I can authenticate and see the homepage.

I've also tried running PhantomJS in Webdriver mode using "-w" and I'm getting a similar result.

It works if I run this script with phantomjs:

```
var page=require('webpage').create();
//page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('xxx:xxx')};
page.settings.userName="xxx";
page.settings.password="xxx";
var callback=function(status){
    if(timer)window.clearTimeout(timer);
    if (status=='success' || status=='timedout') {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(page.plainText);
    }else{
        console.log('Failed to load.');
    }
    phantom.exit();
    };
var timer=window.setTimeout(callback,60000,'timedout');
var url="http://xxx.com";
page.open(url,callback);
```

I copied this script from this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114925/http-authentication-in-phantomjs). I found that with 1.9.1 the userName and password work fine, I didn't need to set a customHeader.  I tried a customHeader in my Selenium script but it didn't make a difference.  This could be an issue with GhostDriver.

Has anyone been able to get this working?

Comment: It looks like the page isn't loading properly.  Have you tried taking a screenshot/grabbing the html source to see what page you are trying to run on looks like?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot is blank and the source is an empty html page.

Answer (score 1):

I am in this exact same situation.

My theory is that we're making the request using NTLM (Windows Authentication), which will solicit a 401 (Unauthorized) and require resending the request with the username/password combination. GhostDriver is quite clear that settings apply [only during the initial call](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html), which would likely obviate the credentials passed in.

It is pretty frustrating that the JavaScript version works so well but the C# version fails so spectacularly.

If there are any suggestions, I would love to hear them.