# PhantomJS Version 1.9.1 - Issues with Proxy Authentication

Tags: authentication, proxy, phantomjs

Can someone please help me out on this?
I have spent a considerable amount of time setting up PhantomJS to save JPGs of specific web-pages and it works/ed really well until I went to deploy it on a machine which accesses the net through a proxy.
Now, whatever I try, I can not get the authentication right?
Has anyone EVER managed to do this?

I am using command line arguments: 
    --proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
    --proxy-type=http
    --proxyAuth=myusername:mypassword

I have checked on the Proxy (TMG) which still insists that my username is anonymous rather than the one which I am sending through using the command line.

From the --debug, I am able to see that proxy, proxyType and proxyAuth have all been populated correctly so PhantomJS is understanding the command line, yet when it runs, it still returns 'Proxy requires authentication'

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for reading this and, hopefully, helping me out

BTW - I am using Windows 7 - 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've done a whole load of digging on this and have got it working. So I thought I would publish what I found in case it might help someone else.

One of the things that I found when I was searching around is that there was a bit of a discussion about the inclusion of the following in the headers which are submitted by the JS which is used to drive PhantomJS:

```
page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password')};
```

rather than using

```
page.settings.userName = 'username';
page.settings.password = 'password';
```

which will not work. Please refer to [Previous Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114925/http-authentication-in-phantomjs)

This is fine if you are using basic levels of authentication on the proxy. It will not work if you are using Integrated Authetication as this will still require NTLM/Kerberos or whatever.

The way around this is to change the settings on the client.

You need to allow the client access to the outside world WITHOUT it routing through the proxy. Certainly in TMG, this is done by changing the settings which apply to the Client Network Software which is installed on the client hardware.

By allowing the PhantomJS Executable to bypass the proxy, you will overcome the problems which I and many others have experienced but you will still have a bit of an issue as you will have just broken your system security so be aware and hope that there is a new version PhantomJS which handles NTLM/Kerberos.

Alternatively, change your Proxy to use Basic Authentication which will allow the use to the customHeaders solution to work as above but this is potentially an even greater risk to you security than allowing the client to bypass the proxyy.

Comment: Ohh, forgot to say: you also need to state 
`--proxy-type=none`
to the command line just to be certain to bypass the proxy

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
fs = require('fs'),
fileName = 'phantomjs',
extension = 'log',
file = fs.open(fileName + '.' + extension, 'w'),
address,
output,
delay,
version = phantom.version.major + '.' 
        + phantom.version.minor + '.' 
        + phantom.version.patch ;

if (system.args.length === 1){
    console.log('Usage: example.js <some URL> delay');
    phantom.exit();
}

// Handle the command line arguments
address = system.args[1];
output  = system.args[2];
delay   = system.args[3];

// Write the Headers into the log file
file.writeLine("PhantomJS version: " + version);
file.writeLine("Opening page: " + address);
file.writeLine("Writing image to: " + output);
file.writeLine("Applying a delay of: " + delay + " milliseconds");

function quit(reason, value) {
    console.log("Quit: " + reason);
    file.writeLine("Quit: " + reason);
    file.close();

    if (value !== 1){
        // If there has been an error reported, stick a datetime stamp on the log to retain it
        var d = new Date();
        var dateString = d.getFullYear().toString() + 
                       ((d.getMonth() + 1) <= 9 ? '0' : '') + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString() +
                        (d.getDate()       <= 9 ? '0' : '') +  d.getDate().toString()       +
                        (d.getHours()      <= 9 ? '0' : '') +  d.getHours().toString()      +
                        (d.getMinutes()    <= 9 ? '0' : '') +  d.getMinutes().toString()    +
                        (d.getSeconds()    <= 9 ? '0' : '') +  d.getSeconds().toString();

        fs.move(fileName + '.' + extension, fileName + '_'  + dateString + '.' + extension);
    }

    phantom.exit(value);
}

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {    
    page.reason = resourceError.errorString;    
    page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
};

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    console.log(msg);
    file.writeLine(msg);

    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
        //file.writeLine('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    })
    quit("Failed", 0);
}

page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    file.writeLine('Request: ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    file.writeLine('Receive: ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};

// Set a user agent - if required
//page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;     SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

// And open the page
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address: \"' + page.reason_url + '\": ' + page.reason);
        file.writeLine('Unable to load the address: \"' + page.reason_url + '\": ' + page.reason);
        quit("Failed", 0);
    } 
    else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Saving the page!');
            file.writeLine('Saving the page!');
            page.render(output);
            quit("Finished", 1);
        }, delay);
    }
});
```