# Http Authentication using JavaScript for PhantomJS and YSlow Integration

Tags: javascript, return-value, phantomjs, http-authentication, yslow

So, I've been having a bit of issues using http://uername:password@someUrl.com for http auth, and I also tried using headers and various other solutions for auth and none worked, except one solution that I found that works well is using JS to login, taken from another solution found here. ([PhantomJS doesn't send authentication header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114925/http-authentication-in-phantomjs)). My question is how can I integrate YSlowJS, PhantomJs and the following script such that when I use I will get the reports returned to me.

```
    $ phantomjs yslow.js myScript.js
      //(this returns) FAIL to load undefined

//This is myScript.js 

var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
t, address;

page.settings.userName = 'test';
page.settings.password = 'test';


address = "http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php";
//using the url from the solution to the link above
page.open(address, function (status)
{
    if (status !== 'success') {

        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    }

    else
    {

        console.log('Page title is ' + page.evaluate(function ()
        {
            return page.open(address); 
            //--> this returns FAIL to load undefined 
            //--> I take it "page" is the issue
        }));


    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Im guessing that the issue is returning the correct variable, if so, what should it be?

Comment: Forgot to mention - pre thanks!