# Node.js throws "btoa is not defined" error

Tags: node.js

In my node.js application I did an `npm install btoa-atob` so that I could use the `btoa()` and `atob()` functions which are native in client-side javascript but for some reason weren't included in node. The new directory showed up in my `node_modules` folder, which itself is in root alongside `app.js`. Then I made sure to add btoa-atob as a dependency in my `package.json` file which is in root.

However, for some reason, it still will not work.

```
console.log(btoa("Hello World!"));
```

^ should output "**SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh**" to the console, but instead, I get the error:

> btoa is not defined.

Did I not do the install properly? What did I overlook?

Answer (score 919, accepted):

The 'btoa-atob' module does not export a programmatic interface, it only provides command line utilities.

If you need to convert to Base64 you could do so using Buffer:

```
console.log(Buffer.from('Hello World!').toString('base64'));
```

Reverse (assuming the content you're decoding is a utf8 string):

```
console.log(Buffer.from(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString());
```

---

Note: prior to Node v4, use `new Buffer` rather than `Buffer.from`.

Comment: This doesn't work in the browser.

Comment: OK. For noobs like me who just want code that includes `btoa` and `atob` to work in some copied code and didn't have a clue what they were for... `btoa` for encoding in base64 (so use `Buffer.from('Hello World!').toString('base64')`) and atob for decoding from base64 (so use `Buffer.from(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString()`).

Answer (score 133):

The solutions posted here don't work in non-ascii characters (i.e. if you plan to exchange base64 between Node.js and a browser). In order to make it work you have to mark the input text as 'binary'.

```
Buffer.from('Hélló wórld!!', 'binary').toString('base64')
```

This gives you `SOlsbPMgd/NybGQhIQ==`. If you make `atob('SOlsbPMgd/NybGQhIQ==')` in a browser it will decode it in the right way. It will do it right also in Node.js via:

```
Buffer.from('SOlsbPMgd/NybGQhIQ==', 'base64').toString('binary')
```

If you don't do the "binary part", you will decode wrongly the special chars.

I got it [from the implementation of the btoa npm package](https://github.com/node-browser-compat/btoa/blob/master/index.js):

Comment: **Iván Alegre** Just don't use 'binary' encoding. If you do `Buffer.from('Hélló wórld!!').toString('base64')` — it will give you `SOlsbPMgd/NybGQhIQ==` which can be converted to non-ascii string back properly.

Comment: @TotalAMD it won't work exchanging base64 from Node.js to browser or viceversa

Comment: @IvánAlegre Just checked a) In Chrome 75: `atob(btoa("Hélló wórld!!")) === "Hélló wórld!!"` b) In Node 10: `Buffer.from('Hélló wórld!!').toString('base64') === 'SMOpbGzDsyB3w7NybGQhIQ=='` and `Buffer.from('SMOpbGzDsyB3w7NybGQhIQ==', 'base64').toString() === 'Hélló wórld!!'` c) Node's `Buffer.from()` can read even if you remove trailing '=', but you can always write simple function to complete encoded string with trailing '='.

Comment: You are comparing encoding in base64 and decoding it in the same platform. Chrome to Chrome and Node to Node.
If you encode it in Node 10 without binary, it will give `SMOpbGzDsyB3w7NybGQhIQ==`. If you decode this in a browser it will give you `HÃ©llÃ³ wÃ³rld!!`. The binary is perfect to ensure cross platform compatibility.

Comment: Your answer in a function:
`function btoa(str){return Buffer.from(str, 'binary').toString('base64');}`
`function atob(str){return Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString('binary');}`

Comment: @IvánAlegre `binary` is just an alias for `latin1` (see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings)), which strips out any non-latin character (Cyrillic, Greek, Chinese, and a ton of other characters). `Buffer.from('Σ', 'binary').toString('base64')'is 'ow=='`, `atob('ow==')` is `£`

Answer (score 37):

My team ran into this problem when using Node with React Native and PouchDB. Here is how we solved it...

NPM install buffer:

```
$ npm install --save buffer
```

Ensure `Buffer`, `btoa`, and `atob` are loaded as a globals:

```
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;

if (typeof btoa === 'undefined') {
  global.btoa = function (str) {
    return new Buffer(str, 'binary').toString('base64');
  };
}

if (typeof atob === 'undefined') {
  global.atob = function (b64Encoded) {
    return new Buffer(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString('binary');
  };
}
```

Comment: The command new Buffer() in your code gives the following error in newer versions of node:
[DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: @RodrigoDeAlmeidaSiqueira, you can use Buffer.from() to fix the warning :)

Answer (score 20):

```
export const universalBtoa = str => {
  try {
    return btoa(str);
  } catch (err) {
    return Buffer.from(str).toString('base64');
  }
};

export const universalAtob = b64Encoded => {
  try {
    return atob(b64Encoded);
  } catch (err) {
    return Buffer.from(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString();
  }
};
```

Comment: universalAtob didn't work for me until I changed it to `Buffer.from(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString('binary');` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890385/470749

Answer (score 17):

I found that although the shims from answers above worked, they did not match the behaviour of desktop browsers' implementations of `btoa()` and `atob()`:

```
const btoa = function(str){ return Buffer.from(str).toString('base64'); }
// returns "4pyT", yet in desktop Chrome would throw an error.
btoa('✓');
// returns "fsO1w6bCvA==", yet in desktop Chrome would return "fvXmvA=="
btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array([0x7e, 0xf5, 0xe6, 0xbc])));
```

As it turns out, `Buffer` instances represent/interpret strings encoded in UTF-8 [by default](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding). By contrast, in desktop Chrome, you can't even input a string that contains characters outside of the latin1 range into `btoa()`, as it will throw an exception: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Therefore, you need to explicitly set the [encoding type](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) to `latin1` in order for your Node.js shim to match the encoding type of desktop Chrome:

```
const btoaLatin1 = function(str) { return Buffer.from(str, 'latin1').toString('base64'); }
const atobLatin1 = function(b64Encoded) {return Buffer.from(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString('latin1');}

const btoaUTF8 = function(str) { return Buffer.from(str, 'utf8').toString('base64'); }
const atobUTF8 = function(b64Encoded) {return Buffer.from(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString('utf8');}

btoaLatin1('✓'); // returns "Ew==" (would be preferable for it to throw error because this is undecodable)
atobLatin1(btoa('✓')); // returns "\u0019" (END OF MEDIUM)

btoaUTF8('✓'); // returns "4pyT"
atobUTF8(btoa('✓')); // returns "✓"

// returns "fvXmvA==", just like desktop Chrome
btoaLatin1(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array([0x7e, 0xf5, 0xe6, 0xbc])));
// returns "fsO1w6bCvA=="
btoaUTF8(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array([0x7e, 0xf5, 0xe6, 0xbc])));
```

Comment: in node v0.12.2 there is not a Buffer.from function

Comment: @Zibri Node v0.12.2 is ancient and reached end-of-life [two years ago](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#end-of-life-releases). `Buffer.from()` is the [recommended way](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/buffer-constructor-deprecation/) to use the Buffer API due to security reasons (although that link will clarify alternatives to `Buffer.from()` that may apply for Node v0.12.2).

Comment: I understand that, but on an embedded device I have that version.

Comment: I am running my code in Atom using the script package https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script that is an old implementation of node. In other words, it also needs an implementation for btoa, while it can't cope with Buffer.from().

Comment: I upvoted this because it's closest to correct. The browser atob / btoa functions specifically need character code points in the range of 0-255. Latin1 is in this range, but doesn't use every character in this range.
The point of btoa and atob is to encode / decode actual binary data for transport over a text channel. If you're encoding / decoding text, atob and btoa are probably unrelated to what you're doing.

Answer (score 12):

I have **a code shared between server and client** and I needed an implementation of btoa inside it.
I tried doing something like:

```
const btoaImplementation =  btoa || (str => Buffer.from(str).toString('base64'));
```

but the Server would crush with:

> ReferenceError: btoa is not defined

while `Buffer` is not defined on the client.

I couldn't check window.btoa (it's a shared code, remember?)

So I ended up with this implementation:

```
const btoaImplementation = str => {
    try {
        return btoa(str);
    } catch(err) {
        return Buffer.from(str).toString('base64')
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

I was able to use `btoa` for binary data to base 64 string conversion using below npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/btoa

As described in their documentation, I did below steps in node JS application:

1. Install => `npm install --save btoa`
2. Declare at top => `const btoa = require('btoa');`
3. Use => `const b64 = btoa("stringToEncode");`

Answer (score 8):

Anybody looking to decode:

`let decoded = Buffer.from(<encoded string>, 'base64').toString()`

Because I came here looking for decoding, ended up figuring it out from an answer here.

Comment: Is this asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: @JCutting8 it is synchronous of course :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a concise universal solution for base64 encoding:

```
const nodeBtoa = (b) => Buffer.from(b).toString('base64');
export const base64encode = typeof btoa !== 'undefined' ? btoa : nodeBtoa;
```

Answer (score 5):

Same problem with the 'script' plugin in the Atom editor, which is an old version of node, not having btoa(), nor atob(), nor does it support the Buffer datatype.  Following code does the trick:

```js
var Base64 = new function() {
  var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="
  this.encode = function(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);
    while (i < input.length) {
      chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
      enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
      enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
      enc4 = chr3 & 63;
      if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
      } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
      }
      output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output;
  }

  this.decode = function(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
    while (i < input.length) {
      enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
      chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
      chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
      output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
      if (enc3 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
      }
      if (enc4 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
      }
    }
    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);
    return output;
  }

  this._utf8_encode = function(string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
      var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      } else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
    }
    return utftext;
  }

  this._utf8_decode = function(utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = 0,
      c1 = 0,
      c2 = 0,
      c3 = 0;
    while (i < utftext.length) {
      c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
      if (c < 128) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(c);
        i++;
      } else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
        i += 2;
      } else {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
        i += 3;
      }
    }
    return string;
  }
}()

var btoa = Base64.encode;
var atob = Base64.decode;

console.log("btoa('A') = " + btoa('A'));
console.log("btoa('QQ==') = " + atob('QQ=='));
console.log("btoa('B') = " + btoa('B'));
console.log("btoa('Qg==') = " + atob('Qg=='));
```

Comment: This works thanks. In my case, I am using ChakraEngine which doesn't seem to support atob.

Answer (score 4):

If you end up here, looking for **atob is not defined** solution (like me). Try upgrade your nodejs version - it helps me

Comment: seems to work fine with the 16.x branch (have not tested it with prior versions)

Comment: `atob()` I think is usually defined under `window`, so in a Node environment without window object, that is not defined, and you must use `Buffer` instead. But Node v16 added the compatibility. Tested on v14.19.3 and 16.15.1

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is a discussion point for a node application, but **in the interest of universal JavaScript applications** running on a node server, which is how I arrived at this post, I have been researching this for a universal / isomorphic react app I have been building, and the package [`abab`](https://github.com/jsdom/abab) worked for me. In fact it was the only solution I could find that worked, rather than using the Buffer method also mentioned (I had typescript issues).

(This package is used by `jsdom`, which in turn is used by the `window` package.)

Getting back to my point; based on this, perhaps if this functionality is already written as an npm package like the one you mentioned, and has it's own algorithm based on W3 spec, you could install and use the `abab` package rather than writing you own function that may or may not be accurate based on encoding.

---**EDIT**---

I started having weird issues today with encoding (not sure why it's started happening now) with package `abab`. It seems to encode correctly most of the time, but sometimes on front end it encodes incorrectly. Spent a long time trying to debug, but switched to package `base-64` as recommended, and it worked straight away. Definitely seemed to be down to the base64 algorithm of `abab`.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in web browsers (where `btoa()` is a global function), in Node.js versions below 16 the `btoa()` function is *not* available in the global namespace. For this reason, in Node.js versions before 16, when you try to access `btoa()` function in the global namespace, it throws a "`btoa is not defined`" error.

Regardless though, `btoa()` is [marked as "legacy"](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/globals.html) in the Node.js documentation, and it is *not* recommended to be used for base64-encoding a string as it cannot handle characters beyond the ASCII/Latin-1 character set. As mentioned in other answers, you should use `Buffer.from()` instead, for example, like so:

```
Buffer.from('Hello World!').toString('base64');
```

Wrote the following blog posts on this topic, which may be useful for those who wish to learn more:

- [Which Characters Are Supported by the JavaScript btoa() Method?](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/which-characters-are-supported-by-the-javascript-btoa-method)
- [How to Fix "`btoa is not defined`" Error in Node.js?](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-btoa-is-not-defined-error-in-node-js)