# Zapier's JavaScript function "btoa" is not defined

Tags: javascript, jwt, zapier

I am trying to make use of existing [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/duncan_passkit_com/mxup0q5z/) for PassKit to create a JWT token with "Run JavaSript by Zapier". But the Zapier does not recognized the btoa function.

> ReferenceError: btoa is not defined

According to this website, this function can be called directly. Any idea?

```
var b64data = btoa("this is my string to turn into base64");
```

Below is the code that I have written.

```
var Zap = {
  base64url:function(input){
    var base64String = btoa(input); //<--error here
    return urlConvertBase64(base64String);
  },
  urlConvertBase64:function(input){
    var output = input.replace(/=+$/, '');
    output = output.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    output = output.replace(/\//g, '_');
    return output;
  },
  generateJWT:function(key){
    var header = {
      "alg": "HS256",
      "typ": "JWT"
    };
    var time_now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    var exp = time_now + 30;
    var body = {
      "exp": exp,
      "key": key
    };
    var token = [];
    token[0] = Zap.base64url(JSON.stringify(header));
    return body;
  }
};
output = [{body: Zap.generateJWT(inputData.Api_key)}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js throws "btoa is not defined" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097928/node-js-throws-btoa-is-not-defined-error)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following:

```
var b64data = Buffer.from('this is my string to turn into base64').toString('base64');
```

Node.js doesn't seem to support the **atob()** and **btoa()** methods.