# Nuxt URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hi guys I'm working with [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/)

And I have image saved on server as blob that I would like to display on client

My Component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="product-page">
    <div class="product-image">
      <img data-image="black" :src="{imgSrc}" alt class="active" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
      <h3>{{ product.price }}</h3>
      <div class="description">
        <p>The purposes of bonsai are primarily contemplation for the viewer, and the pleasant exercise of effort and ingenuity for the grower.</p>
        <p>By contrast with other plant cultivation practices, bonsai is not intended for production of food or for medicine. Instead, bonsai practice focuses on long-term cultivation and shaping of one or more small trees growing in a container.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    imgSrc() {
      const src = URL.createObjectURL(this.product.images.data);
      return src;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Bu I keep getting following error:

**URL.createObjectURL is not a function**

Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

Comment: In what [mode](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode/) are you using nuxt ?
And does the error happen on the browser or server ?

Comment: Related GH issues with info: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error likely occurs on the server side, as Node does not support `URL.createObjectURL()`. Instead, you could create a [data URL for your image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/6277151) in this format:

```
data:image/png;BASE64_OF_IMG_BLOB
```

where `BASE64_OF_IMG_BLOB` is computed from:

- *Node:* [`blob.toString('base64')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097961/6277151)
- *Browser:* [`btoa(blob)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/6277151)

`imgSrc` would then look like this:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    imgSrc() {
      const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
      const blob = this.product.images.data
      const base64 = isServer ? blob.toString('base64') : btoa(blob)
      return 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `:src` binding should be updated to remove the curly brackets:

```html
<img :src="{imgSrc}"> ❌ brackets unnecessary
<img :src="imgSrc"> ✅
```