# How to encode base64 in an Azure Devops Pipelines extension

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm developing an Azure Pipelines extension in Typescript following [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops)

At some point I need to encode base64 a string. I tried using the `btoa()` function but the pipeline fails -> `##[error]btoa is not defined`

```
async function run() {
    try {

    const someString = "xxx"
   
    //Encode Base64 someString
    const sonarqubeTokenBase64 = btoa(`${someString}:`)

    } catch (err) {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
    }
}
```

How can I encode a string in this extension?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097961/1658906