# How can I tell which javascript libraries are built-in, and what can I do if I want to use a function from a library that's not built-in?

Tags: javascript, base64, karate

I want to read in a file, get it's size in bytes, and get its contents as a base64 string.

I was thinking to use the [enclosed javascript](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#enclosed-javascript) functionality of karate, because it's so convenient.

I tried this:

```
 * def fileToAdd = 'test.pdf'
 * def fileToAddAsString = read(fileToAdd)
 * def fileToAddByteSize = (fileToAddAsString.length)
 * def fileToAddAsBase64 = (btoa(fileToAddAsString))
```

but the last line failed, as shown by the following output:

```
>>> failed features:
js failed:
>>>>
01: (btoa(fileToAddAsString))
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "btoa" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Any ideas how to work-around this?  I assume that the builtin javascript engine doesn't have the library that defines [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa), but i don't know if that can be overcome, and if so, how.

Since my file is static, I could hardcode the base64 encoding of its contents, but I'd rather make it easier to change the file in the future, by having the code compute it for me, so i don't have to update the fileToAddAsBase64.

Please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this in Node.js? If so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097928/node-js-throws-btoa-is-not-defined-error

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript. JavaScript declares variables with `var`, `let`, and `const`, not `def`.

Comment: it's karate (https://github.com/karatelabs/karate), which has a javascript engine built into it, and karate's 'enclosed javascript' syntax.  The read and the file size bits work fine.

Comment: I think karate uses graalvm (https://www.graalvm.org/javascript/)

Comment: Isn't Karate based on Java, not JavaScript ?

Comment: There is a compatibility table for each J's feature on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa or you can use https://caniuse.com/?search=btoa

Comment: @JonDetert the linked answer has all the details you need. the recommendation is that for this case (base64 encoding) just tap into the Java classes in the underlying JVM, it is pretty simple and you don't need to compile any java code